# Serverless :: AWS profile ""workflow"" doesn't seem to be configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I had added a new profile, **workflow**, using

```
    aws configure
```

I have created a serverless application using

```
    serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path ssm5
```

/.aws/credentials

```
    [workflow]
    aws_access_key_id=<<My Access Key>>
    aws_secret_access_key=<<My Secret Key>>
```

/.aws/config

```
    [profile workflow]
    region = us-east-1
```

serverless.yml

```
    service: ssm5
    frameworkVersion: "2"

    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs12.x
      lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
```

I tried to deploy the application using

```
    serverless deploy --aws-profile workflow
```

Unfortunately I am getting below error.

```
    Serverless: Packaging service...
    Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
    Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
    AWS profile ""workflow"" doesn't seem to be configured
```

I had then set below environment variables from command prompt.

```
    set AWS_PROFILE="workflow"
    set AWS_ACCESS_KEY=<<My Access Key>>
    set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<<My Secret Key>>
    set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

Unfortunately, that also didn't help me and the error still prevails.

Note: I used terraform to provision infrastructure. Terraform picks the **workflow** profile successfully from the aforementioned config & credential files. Problem is only with serverless.

It would be really great if someone can help me on this.

Comment: can you try with this first `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` and then `sls deploy --profile workflow`

Comment: I tried with sls deploy --profile workflow. Still I am getting the same error. I used setx AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG 1 command, as export is a unix command. setx is its equivalent for Windows.

Comment: run this in your terminal `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` and then run deploy command

Comment: Also I think things are working with respect to aws profile as Terraform picks it and created infrastructure for me successfully. I experience the issue only with serverless.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and after debugging the code, I found this:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/29f0e9c840e4b1ae9949925bc5a2a9d2de742271/lib/plugins/aws/provider.js#L129

Since by default AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials does not return the roleArn by default, sls assumes the profile is invalid. The fix is to set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 as suggested in the comments. That variable tells the AWS SDK to load the profile when you are using a shared config file.

Based on that I can assume that setting AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE *might* work as well since the other file should only contain the one profile.